# Is there something like nvenc for free codecs (VP8/9)?

Tags: encoding, codec, hardware

I'm new to video encoding. And I was looking at h264/265 and VP8/9.
I'd like to use VP8/9. But it seems like nobody except Google is pushing it.
I just want to know does someone else support VP8/9? Specefically is there a hardware acceleration for encoding.
And **de**coding VP**9** on my Linux box looks very slow (when navigating in video it lags for 2sec, while vp8 is instant).

Answer (score 3):

There is a hardware-accelerated VP8 encoder recently released by the University of Milan. Source and standalone binary for 64-bit Linux and  compute 3.5, 5.0 and 5.2 capable NVidia GPU cards available at https://github.com/Italtel-Unimi/libvpx

They say they have integrated the code into libav libs i.e. FFmpeg, but this hasn't been pushed into the FFmpeg master branch.

Comment: Cool! Do you know why it is not part of ffmpeg yet?

Comment: Recently released, so it has to be tested and committed into libvpx master, then their libav code will be tested and pushed into FFmpeg.